# Why is this proof on rational set valid?

Tags: proof-writing, irrational-numbers

> Prove that if $y$ is rational and $x$ is irrational, then $y + x$ and $yx$ (assume y $\neq 0 $) is irrational.

I kinda guessed the proof and it turned out to be right with the key, but it doesn't answer my question. Here is my quick and dirty proof

> Assume $x + y$ is rational such that $x + y = r$ ($r$ is rational), then $x + y = r \iff x = r - y \iff x = r + (-y)$ 
>    But this is a contradiction since $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed under addition.

Q1. Okay so I showed that by contradiction that my claim is wrong, but showing that something isn't doesn't tell us what the original thing was now does it? Or does this work because *rational* and *irrational* are polar opposites and I don't need to fill in?

The proof for multiplication is similar:

> Assume $xy$ is rational such that $xy = r$ ($r$ is rational), then $xy = r \iff x = r/y$ 
>   But this is a contradiction since $\mathbb{Q}$ is closed under division

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These arguments are just fine. In each you’ve shown that the assumption that a certain number is rational leads to a contradiction. This means that the assumption cannot be true: the number in question cannot be rational. But a real number that is not rational is by definition irrational, so you’ve shown that the number in question is irrational.

Comment: Could you join the chat, professor?